# how to calculate minutes difference between 10:00 AM to 1:00 PM in javascript?

Tags: javascript

These are my variables;

```
 var start = "10:20 AM";
 var end = "10:30 AM";
```

I want to find time difference in minutes. How can I do that?

Comment: What did you try? Please don't expect that someone will code it for you. And if you are too lazy to try, a simple google search would have got you an answer.

Comment: How is the input being taken in. Is it hardcoded as in the question or is it from user input etc.

Comment: Use http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var start = "10:20 AM";
var end = "10:30 AM";

// convert into something like a unix timestamp by adding a date
start = new Date('01.01.1970 '+start).getTime() / 1000;
end = new Date('01.01.1970 '+end).getTime() / 1000;

// time diff in minutes
var result = Math.abs(end - start) / 60;
```

Answer (score 0):

I recomend to use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) to work with date/time, it helps a lot. ;)

```
var diff = moment(end, 'HH:mm A').diff(moment(start, 'HH:mm A'), 'minutes');
```